# TFS: Create individual Bug items when XUnit tests fail

Tags: testing, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, xunit

Our goal is to implement CI testing and deployment for our DEV web environments:

**Goal**

1. Run XUnit tests on check-in.
2. If tests fail, create individual, associated Bug work items. Stop.
3. If tests tests pass, deploy build to a UNC file path.

**Current Setup**

CI is on for the branch, and the build definition currently has enabled `Create Work Item on Failure` on the `Options` panel.

XUnit was integrated into the `Visual Studio Test` build step by providing the `Path to Custom Test Adapters` necessary.

**Problem**

Tests run and display results correctly in the build, but no bugs are created for the failed tests, only one for the overall build fail.

**Question**

How can I create individual Bugs (and include details about the bug in its description)?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own code to create Bugs for each test failure.

I would however recommend against it as this creates unessesery work items and they may not really be bugs. Maybe we have a single test that fails, and the other 200 tests fail as a result. We only have one bug. You will overwhelm people.

You can easily create bugs as you investigate failures using the failed test list that is part of the build results.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-continuous-testing

Comment: I thought it already did so for MS Tests failed. I'm just trying to replicate that for the XUnit test adapter. I'm not sure why you have tests that depend on the success or failure of other tests either - pretty bad practice in my opinion.

Comment: There are many legitimate circumstances where a single code change will fail many tests.

Comment: Of course! A single byte may fail any number of tests, but you said "we have a single test that fails, and the other 200 tests fail as a result." Failures causing other test failures.

Comment: It could be and is very common. Not all tests are Unit Tests and many are Integration or System Tests. These may have dependencies...That is just a reality of trying to test poorly written software... which most companies have.